# Pickling Error with Spark-Submit "_pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from __newobj__ args has the wrong class"

Tags: python, pyspark, pickle, user-defined-functions, apache-zeppelin

I am getting the following error when trying to run some code through Spark-Submit or Zeppelin: "_pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from __ newobj __ args has the wrong class"

I have looked around at posts with the same problem and haven't much insight into this issue.

The traceback (included below) points to one of the udfs I use:

```
udf_stop_words = udf(stop_words, ArrayType(StringType()))

def stop_words(words):
    return list(word.lower() for word in words if word.lower() not in  stopwords.words("english"))
```

Both the input and output of the function are lists of strings. These are 3 rows from the input:

> [Row(split_tokenized_activity_description=['A', 'delightful', '45',
>   'minute', 'Swedish', 'style', 'massage']),
>   Row(split_tokenized_activity_description=['A', 'more', 'intense',
>   '45', 'minute', 'version', 'of', 'a', 'Swedish', 'style', 'massage']),
>   Row(split_tokenized_activity_description=['A', 'relaxing', '45',
>   'minute', 'Swedish', 'style', 'massage'])

This is a snippet of the code I'm working with.

```
def special_car(x):
    # remove the special character and replace them with the stop word " " (space)
    return [re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', x)]

# Create UDF from function
udf_special_car = udf(special_car, ArrayType(StringType()))

# Function to remove stops words
def stop_words(words):
    return list(word.lower() for word in words if word.lower() not in  stopwords.words("english"))

udf_stop_words = udf(stop_words, ArrayType(StringType()))

# Load in data
df_tags = spark.sql("select * from database")

# Remove special Characters
df1_tags = df_tags.withColumn('tokenized_name', udf_special_car(df_tags.name))
df2_tags = df1_tags.withColumn('tokenized_description', udf_special_car(df1_tags.description))

# Select only relevent columns
df3_tags = df2_tags.select(['tag_id', 'tokenized_name', 'tokenized_description'])

# Tokenize tag_name and tag_desc (Seperate on spaces) (This uses the pyspark.sql.split function)
df4_tags = df3_tags.withColumn('split_tokenized_name', split(df3_tags['tokenized_name'].getItem(0), ' '))
df5_tags = df4_tags.withColumn('split_tokenized_description', split(df3_tags['tokenized_description'].getItem(0), ' '))

# Select only relevent columns
df6_tags = df5_tags.select(['tag_id', 'split_tokenized_name', 'split_tokenized_description'])

# Remove Stop words
df7_tags = df6_tags.withColumn('stop_words_tokenized_name', udf_stop_words(df6_tags.split_tokenized_name))
df8_tags = df7_tags.withColumn('stop_words_tokenized_description', udf_stop_words(df7_tags.split_tokenized_description))
```

Oddly, First TWO TIMES running my code through Zeppelin I get the error, but after the 3rd try, it runs just fine, and the output is how I expect it to be. Zeppelin is only for testing, though; I need to get this to run through Spark-Submit.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/tmp/testing_test.py", line 262, in 
>       udf_stop_words = udf(stop_words, ArrayType(StringType()))   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line
>   1872, in udf   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line
>   1830, in **init**   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line
>   1835, in _create_judf   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line
>   1815, in _wrap_function   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2359, in
>   _prepare_for_python_RDD   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line
>   460, in dumps   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line
>   703, in dumps   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line
>   147, in dump   File "/home/hadoop/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pickle.py",
>   line 409, in dump
>       self.save(obj)   File "/home/hadoop/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
>       f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self   File "/home/hadoop/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 736, in
>   save_tuple
>       save(element)   File "/home/hadoop/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
>       f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line
>   248, in save_function   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line
>   296, in save_function_tuple   File
>   "/home/hadoop/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
>       f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self   File "/home/hadoop/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in
>   save_dict
>       self._batch_setitems(obj.items())   File "/home/hadoop/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 852, in
>   _batch_setitems
>       save(v)   File "/home/hadoop/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
>       self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line
>   564, in save_reduce
>   _pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from **newobj** args has the wrong class

I have tried several things to resolve this issue, and none of them have worked. They all return the same error.

I have tried changing the udf to be a one-line lambda function:

```
udf(lambda words: list(word.lower() for word in words if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')), ArrayType(StringType())).
```

I have tried changing the udf to return a string:

```
udf_stop_words = udf(stop_words, StringType())
```

and changing the udf a bit to match.

```
def stop_words(words):
    return str(word.lower() for word in words if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english'))
```

I have tried to define it as a StructType with both:

```
udf_stop_words = udf(stop_words, StructType([StructField("words", ArrayType(StringType()), False)]))
```

and

```
udf_stop_words = udf(stop_words, StructType([StructField("words", StringType(), False)])).
```

I have also tried many combinations of the above.

Comment: Can you add more context of your application? (like all the code and sample data) And full traceback for the error?

Answer (score 1):

The return type should be an `ArrayType(StringType())`.

I am not sure about this, but maybe the problem comes from the fact that you don't have `nltk` installed on your nodes (or the `corpus` `stopwords` was never downloaded on the nodes). Since calling `stopwords.words("english")` inside your `UDF` is like calling it on the nodes, it might fail because it can't find the corpus.

Since `stopwords.words("english")` is just a list, you should call it on your driver and then broadcast it to the nodes:

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
english_stopwords = stopwords.words("english")
sc.broadcast(english_stopwords)
def stop_words(words):
    return list(word.lower() for word in words if word.lower() not in english_stopwords)

from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
udf_stop_words = psf.udf(stop_words, ArrayType(StringType()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case the exception was being thrown because i defined a class inside my spark script itself. It was resolved by creating a separate .py file containing the class definition and methods. Then add that script to your script by `sc.addPyFile(path)` and finally `from FileName import *`.