# Saving an object with Pandas DataFrames and Spacy objects using dill: "_pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from __newobj__ args has the wrong class"

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, spacy, dill

I have the following code:

```py
# imports, e.g. pandas, dill, spacy, nltk

class CxG:

    # ...

    def generate_features(self, document: Doc, token: Token):
        # Function needs to be self-contained, so that it can be parallelized -> import everything locally here:
        from nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet import WordNetCorpusReader as wncr
        from src.modules.wsd import lesk  # TODO Import from nltk, as soon as lang is in the current version
        from src.slot import LexSlot, MorphSlot, SynSlot, SemSlot

        pos = token.pos_ if token.pos_ else None
        lemma = token.lemma_
        morph = str(token.morph) if token.morph else None
        synset = None
        if pos in dir(wncr):  # if the pos tag is available in wordnet
            wn_pos = getattr(wncr, pos)  # get the wordnet pos tag
            # Get the most probable synset using Lesk's algorithm:
            synset = lesk(document.text, lemma, pos=wn_pos, lang=self.language)
            if synset:
                return LexSlot(pos, morph, synset, token.text), SemSlot(pos, morph, synset), 1  # pos, morph, synset, 1
        if morph:
            return LexSlot(pos, morph, synset, token.text), MorphSlot(pos, morph), 1  # pos, morph, None, 1
        else:
            return LexSlot(pos, morph, synset, token.text), SynSlot(pos), 1
        return LexSlot(pos, morph, synset, token.text), None, 1

    def collect_features_for_document(self, document, get_all=False):
        token_features = []
        for token in document:
            if get_all:  # get all features
                token_features.append(self.generate_features(document, token))
            else:  # only get the LexSlot
                token_features.append(self.generate_features(document, token)[0])
        return tuple(token_features)

    def collect_document_features(self, save=False, parallel=False):
        documents = self.data.documents["document"]
        if parallel:
            document_features = [
                self.collect_features_for_document(document) for document
                in tqdm(self.nlp.pipe(documents, n_process=os.cpu_count()),# batch_size=300),
                        desc="Collecting features per document",
                        total=len(documents))
            ]
        else:
            document_features = []
            for document in tqdm(documents, desc="Collecting features per document"):
               token_features = []
               for token in document:
                   # Retrieve the features for each token in the current document:
                   token_features.append(self.generate_features(document, token)[0])
               document_features.append(tuple(token_features))  # store the slots for each token in a tuple

        self.data.documents["features"] = pd.DataFrame({"features": document_features})

        if save:
            self.save_cxg()

    # ...

    def save_cxg(self):
        print("Saving CxG to file...", file=sys.stderr)
        # Create directories if they don't exist:
        if not os.path.exists(self.save_path):
            os.makedirs(self.save_path)
        with open(f"{self.save_path}/cxg.dill", "wb") as f:
            dill.dump(self, f)
        print("Done saving!", file=sys.stderr)
```

This leads to the following error as soon as the code reaches `self.save_cxg()`:

```
...

Collecting features per document: 100%|██████████| 118579/118579 [14:20<00:00, 137.74it/s]
Saving CxG to file...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[…]/c3xg/src/cxg.py", line 442, in <module>
    cxg_english.collect_document_features(save=True, parallel=True)
  File "[…]/c3xg/src/cxg.py", line 160, in collect_document_features
    self.save_cxg()
  File "[…]/c3xg/src/cxg.py", line 385, in save_cxg
    dill.dump(self, f)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 250, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol, **_kwds).dump(obj)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 418, in dump
    StockPickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 487, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 717, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1212, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 972, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 998, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 717, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1212, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 972, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 998, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 717, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1212, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 972, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 998, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 692, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 887, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 887, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 692, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 887, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 404, in save_numpy_array
    pickler.save_reduce(_create_array, (f,args,state,npdict), obj=obj)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 692, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 902, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 902, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 932, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 956, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 902, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 692, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 902, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 717, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 887, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1212, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 972, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 998, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 717, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1212, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 972, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 998, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "[…]/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "[…]/anaconda3/envs/c3xg/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 684, in save_reduce
    raise PicklingError(
_pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from __newobj__ args has the wrong class
```

I saw similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878186/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911539/), but I couldn't see any similarities to my code. I have the suspicion that it might have something to do with Spacy's `nlp` object, because I found issues like [this](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/767) which relate somewhat to the usage of Spacy and multiprocessing.

What could be the reason that saving the CxG object showed in the code above is not possible?